# How to set fixed height of text input and stop overlapping of two text input in kivy?

Tags: kivy, textinput

Basically i want fixed text input height and don'n overlap two textinput

```
TextInput:
    focus:True # cursor into textfield
    cursor_color: .26,.26,.3,1  #cursor color
        #size_hint: None, 1
    #size: self.texture_size


    foreground_color: .26,.26,.3,1 # Input text color
    pos: root.width * .24,root.height * .47
    width: root.width * .55
    height:'34dp'
    size_hint: (.2, None)
        #size: (min(self.width,self.height),min(self.width,self.height))
        #size_hint_min_y:self.minimum_height #used for fixed minimum height
        #height:root*.9
        #height:self.minimum_height
    font_size:root.height * .03
    hint_text:"please Enter your captha"
    multiline:False 
    background_normal: "resource/images/rounded-image-green.jpg"
    background_active: "resource/images/rounded-image-red.jpg"

    padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
```

Comment: That code that shows that it has to do with your question? Where are the 2 TextInputs?

Comment: don't use text hint that might work